# Add Query Parameter in action url within action after action is called

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, url-parameters, actionresult

I am migrating an application from Struts 1 to Struts 2. I have a usecase here. Struts1 action adds a query String in the URL like this:

```
 public String execute() throws Exception {
     ..... some code here.....
     ActionForward inputForward = HttpRedirector.getRedirectToInput(request,
     mapping, "id=" + request.getParameter("id") + "&" + 
     request.getQueryString(), filterForm);

     return inputForward;

 }
```

when it redirects to `input` page the URL is modified like this:

```
http://localhost:8084/struts2App/board.jsp?id=1&null
```

Similarly, I have to add Query String in my Struts 2 action URL. Currently my Struts 2 action URL looks like this when I submit the form:

```
localhost:8084/struts2App/board.action
```

And I want to modify it, the same way it is done in struts1 like this:

```
http://localhost:8084/struts2App/board.action?id=1&null
```

Here is the struts2 action mapping

```
    <action name="board*" class="com.nextjet.web.hud.BoardAction">
        <result name="success">/board.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/board.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve it.

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/redirect-action-result.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM OP has not assigned any variable name to pass the `request.getQueryString()`, in that case adding `<param />` tag is not possible.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan What?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can return [`redirectAction` result](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/redirect-action-result):

```xml
<action name="board*" class="com.nextjet.web.hud.BoardAction">
    <result name="success">/board.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/board.jsp</result>
    <result name="redirect" type="redirectAction">
      <param name="actionName"><![CDATA[${'board.action?'+ parameters}]]></param>
    </result>
</action>
```

You should have getter for `parameters`:

```
public String getParameters(){
   return "id=" + request.getParameter("id") + "&" + request.getQueryString();
}
```